# How is the norm of a partition related to the norm of a vector?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, vector-spaces

Just finished a course in linear algebra, where the norm of a vector essentially was described as the length of the vector. In calculus, we just started talking about the definite integral of a function, where the norm of a partition came up, being defined as the max size of a subinterval given a set of subintervals.

Are these two uses of norm related, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max size of the absolute value of a finite list of numbers is the infinity-norm of that list.  This is an example of a [p-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions).  For $p=2$ you get the Euclidean norm that you're familiar with.

Comment: I like this connection, but the "vector addition" on the set of partitions of seems odd.  If $\cal{P}_1=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $\cal{P}_2=\{0,2,\frac{5}{2},3\}$ are partitions of $[0,3]$, then $\|\cal{P}_1\|=\|\mathbf{v=(1,1,1)}\| = \max\{1,1,1\}$ and $\|\cal{P}_2\|=\|\mathbf{w=(2,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}\|=\max\{2,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\}$.  This being the case, how do we define $\|\cal{P}_1+\cal{P}_2\|$?  (It does not seem natural to make $\|\cal{P}_1 +\cal{P}_2\|=\|\mathbf{v+w}\|=\|(3,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})\|$, which would correspond to a partition of $[0,6]$ or $[-3,3]$, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @vadim said, it is just used because of norm-like properties such as
$$
\|\mathcal{P}\| > 0
$$
for any partition $\mathcal{P}$, and
$$
\|\mathcal{P}_1\cup\mathcal{P}_2\| \leq \max\{\|\mathcal{P}_1\|, \|\mathcal{P}_2\|\}
$$
In other words, it is some measure of the size of a partition that behaves well with respect to the algebraic operations that one can perform on partitions.